# SQL Help(Date Functions)

Tags: sql, sqlplus, sql-date-functions

I need help on SQL Queries.
TABLE:

```
Create Table Employees
        ( employee_id   number(3) Primary Key,
          first_name    varchar2(10),
          last_name varchar2(10),
          dept_code varchar2(3),
          hire_date date,
          credit_limit  number(4,2),
          phone_ext varchar2(4),
          manager_id    number(3)
        );
```

Entries:

```
insert into Employees values (201, 'Susan', 'Brown', 'Exe', To_Date('01-Jun-1998','DD-Mon-YYYY'), 30, '3484', null);
insert into Employees values (202, 'Jim', 'Kern', 'Sal', To_Date('16-Aug-1999','DD-Mon-YYYY'), 25, '8722', 201);
insert into Employees values (203, 'Martha', 'Woods', 'Shp', To_Date('02-Feb-2004','DD-Mon-YYYY'), 25, '7591', 201);    
insert into Employees values (204, 'Ellen', 'Owens', 'Sal', To_Date('01-Jul-2003','DD-Mon-YYYY'), 15, '6830', 202);
```

I need a query to List all the employees, their hire dates and the number of days each person will have worked for the company as of January 1, 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `YEAR()` on a date field:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE YEAR(hire_date)='2003'
```

if it doesn't work, you can use `EXTRACT()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)='2003'
```

and, as Alan Hadsell rightly commented:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)='2003'
```

Comment: Since he wants the number of employees, it should be `select count(*)` rather than `select *`.   But you have the essence of the answer right.